# Oracle invalid identifier in subquery

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having this query:

```
SELECT
    XMLELEMENT("row", XMLATTRIBUTES(productMain.variant as "order"),
        (SELECT XMLELEMENT("attribute", XMLATTRIBUTES(product.id as "id") )
        FROM product where product.variant = productMain.variant
        )
    )

FROM
    (SELECT 
        DISTINCT product.variant 
    FROM 
        product
    WHERE
        product.fk_parent = 12345) productMain
```

and I'm getting an error *'invalid identifier `productMain.variant`'*.

**Expected result:**

```
<row order="1">
    <attribute name="Example1"/>
    <attribute name="Example2"/>
    ...
</row>
<row order="2">
    ...
</row>
```

**Table `product`:**

```
id | variant | name
_________________________
1  | 1       | Example1
2  | 1       | Example2
3  | 2       | Example3
4  | 3       | Example4
5  | 3       | Example5
```

...

**SQLFIDDLE:**
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e91a6/2

What I found out, is that Oracle doesn't correlate the subqueries nested more than one level deep.

How do I still get the result I want?

Comment: Your table names and aliases are very confusing, please fix.

Comment: sorry @Colin'tHart. Fixed now.

Comment: Almost, please fix the error message too: is it `product.variant` or `productMain.variant` there?

Comment: Yes its "productMain.variant". It doesnt know the value from the other subselect. Oracle doesn't correlate the subqueries nested more than one level deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT
XMLELEMENT("row", XMLATTRIBUTES(productMain.variant as "order"),

  (
  SELECT 
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("attribute",XMLATTRIBUTES(product.name as "name"),product.variant)) FROM product 
    where product.fk_parent = 12345
    and product.variant = productmain.variant
  )

).getClobVal()

FROM
(SELECT 
    DISTINCT product.variant 
FROM 
    product
WHERE
    product.fk_parent = 12345) productMain;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
XMLELEMENT("row", XMLATTRIBUTES(productMain.variant as "order"),
    (SELECT XMLELEMENT("attribute", XMLATTRIBUTES(product.id as "id") )
    FROM product,
    (SELECT DISTINCT variant FROM 
    product
    WHERE fk_parent = 12345) as productMain 
    where product.variant = productMain.variant
    )
)

FROM
(SELECT 
    DISTINCT variant 
FROM 
    product
WHERE
    fk_parent = 12345) productMain
```

Comment: single-row subquery returns more than one row